# On android 4.4.2 ,the AlarmManager service don't work correctly

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I'm using `AlarmManager` as below,but it is not working on KITKAT.
The `BroadCastReceiver` doesn't receive the action

1. first step: get the `PendingIntent`:

   ```
   long now = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
   Intent wakeIntent = new Intent(AlarmDetectService.this, GlobalBroadcastAction.class);
   wakeIntent.setAction(Constant.TCP_KEEP_ALIVE_TIMER);
   wakeIntent.putExtra(Constant.TARGET_SERVER,server_Address);
   alivePi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
           AlarmDetectService.this, requestCode, wakeIntent,
           PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);//request_code is server_address's hashCode.
   ```
2. second step:

   ```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
       Log.w(TAG, "Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT");
       aliveAm.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
           (long) (now + keepAliveTime * 1000 * 0.8),
           (PendingIntent) alivePi);
   } else {
       aliveAm.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
           (long) (now + keepAliveTime * 1000 * 0.8),
           (PendingIntent) alivePi);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is added in API 19:

> Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will
>   shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are
>   new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery
>   guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and
>   setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose
>   targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the
>   previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when
>   requested.

from AlarmManager.

> ***Important:***

setExact() still does not have to be exact, as the docs state:

> The alarm will be delivered as nearly as possible to the requested
>   trigger time.

Comment: In my mainfest.xml,i had set  targetSDK = 21.

Comment: I also try this on android6.0 ,and it work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write separate methods:

```
private void setAlarm(AlarmManager am, long interval, PendingIntent pi){
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + interval, pi);
    }

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        private void setAlarmToKitkat(AlarmManager am, long interval, PendingIntent pi){
            am.setWindow(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + interval, 20000, pi);
        }
```

and when you call it:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) 
        {
            setAlarm(am, interval, pi);
        }
        else
        {
            setAlarmToKitkat(am, interval, pi);     
        }
```

Comment: In the method setWindow ，will it repeat?i need AM to do once, And,how i understand the second and thrid parameter?

Comment: Today,i try it on android4.4.2 use the setWindow but it still doesn't work

Comment: Please read about setWindow and its parameters here (It sets the alarm only once, it won't repeat) : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setWindow(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)

Comment: Thanks，do you know when my phone is enter power saving mode，why AlarmManager doesn‘t execute the task。i need it can execute even if it enter power saving mode。